# Let $A$ be complex matrix and $x$ be eigenvalue of $A\overline{A}$. Algebraic multiplicity of $x$ is even.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be non-singular $n\times n$ complex matrices and $x$ be negative eigenvalue of $A\overline{A}$. Show that algebraic multiplicity of $x$ is an even number.

I show that the $\det(A\overline{A})>0$, so the number of negative eigenvalue is even. But I'm stuck to prove algebraic multiplicity of $x$ is an even number.

Comment: What happens if $A$ is $1\times 1$?

Comment: Properties like this usually appearance in the discussion of *"consimilarity"*. For the current problem, see exercise 7(c) in chapter 4.6 on p.253 of the first edition of Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis*. Their proof makes use of eigenvectors. I believe there is a proof without eigenvectors, but I haven't time to delve into it.

Answer (score 5):

$\textbf{Proposition.}$ If $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $\lambda\in\mathrm{Spec}(A\overline{A})\cap (-\infty,0)$, then $\lambda$ has an even algebraic multiplicity.

$\textbf{Proof}.$ The key is: "there are $S\in GL_n(\mathbb{C}),R\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $A=S{R\overline{S}}\;^{-1}$" (Corollary 4.6.15 in *Matrix Analysis* by Horn and Johnson, 2013, cited by user1551 -who has good readings-).
Then $A\overline{A}=SR^2S^{-1}$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(A\overline{A})=\{\mu^2;\mu\in\mathrm{Spec}(R)\}$ (equality of lists).
Thus $\pm i\sqrt{-\lambda}$ are eigenvalues of the real matrix $R$; since they have same multiplicity, $\lambda$ has even algebraic multiplicity. $\square$

$\textbf{Remark}.$ That implies the famous result $\det(I+A\overline{A})\geq 0$.

Indeed, $\det(I+A\overline{A})=\det(I+R^2)=\det((I+iR)(I-iR))=\det(I+iR)\det(I-iR)=\det(I+iR)\overline{\det(I+iR)}\ge0$.